# Unexpected MySQL Transaction Commit

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, odbc

I have a PHP script that works with both a MySQL database and an ODBC DB connection (QODBC into QuickBooks).  The setup is like this:

```
Retrieve rows from MySQL database
Begin MySQL transaction:
    Loop through rows
    Process data
    MySQL Insert/Update
    MySQL Update
    QODBC Selects/Inserts
End Loop
    MySQL Delete
Commit Transaction
```

The problem is, if there is an error in the QODBC section, the MySQL commands up to that point will be committed.  This is leading to duplicate and wrong data in MySQL. There are no nested transactions and all the queries success/failure is being addressed (ie no fatal errors or premature exiting of a script).

The question is - is there a problem when connecting to two different databases via PHP, in the same script?  What seems to be happening is when the script gets to the ODBC section, the MySQL transaction is closed and auto-committed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say there are two potential reasons:

- Your tables were created using MyISAM which does not support transactions
- Your connection is set to autocommit

Comment: You should use InnoDB for using transaction in mySQL.

Comment: All tables are INNODB.  The connection is set to autocommit (mysql default), but reading through the MySQL documentation, by issuing the Begin; statement, the autocommit is disabled for the following queries.  So, as far as I understand it, all the queries that happen in the loop should be committed at once - not when the connection to the ODBC DB is made.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "when the connection to the ODBC is made" part? Are you opening a second connection? Is it possible that opening that connection implicitely closes the first connection? Sorry, I don't know PHP, so I can only guess.

Comment: Turns out that while I thought I had converted the tables to INNODB, I hadn't.  Lesson learned - check all settings before posting to the forum.